# Rotate ggplot map so that north is to the left instead of up

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I need to plot a map of Chile “sideways”, i.e., with the north pointing left. The map is plotted using `ggplot` and `sf` packages, with geometry coming from the [chilemapas package](https://pacha.dev/chilemapas/index.html). IS this something possible to do using `coord_sf()`, or should I modify geometry in some way?

Example of a map of Chile in ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("chilemapas")
library(chilemapas)

poblacion_adulto_mayor_regiones <- censo_2017_comunas %>% 
  left_join(codigos_territoriales) %>% 
  group_by(codigo_region) %>% 
  summarise(pob_adulto_mayor = sum(poblacion))
#> Joining, by = "codigo_comuna"

region_los_rios <- mapa_comunas %>% 
  #filter(codigo_region == 14) %>% 
  generar_regiones() %>% 
  left_join(
    codigos_territoriales %>% 
      select(matches("region")) %>% 
      distinct()
  ) %>% 
  left_join(poblacion_adulto_mayor_regiones)

ggplot(region_los_rios) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pob_adulto_mayor, geometry = geometry)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 13) +
  coord_sf()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, crs 3338 gets you pretty close to what you are after (i think). Maybe there are other crs or approaches with geometry?

```
library(ggspatial)
ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(data=region_los_rios, 
                                aes(fill = pob_adulto_mayor, 
                                    geometry = geometry)) +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 13) +
      ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(location = "br", which_north = "true")+
      coord_sf(crs = 3338)
```